# IntelliJ 2020.2 Jakarta EE 9 support

Tags: intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

When I create new Jakarta EE 9 project in IntelliJ IDEA and then create i.e. new servlet (using New > Servlet wizard), IntelliJ creates old Java EE annotated class with javax.* imports and I have to fix everything manually.

Is it possible to switch old imports to the new namespace (jakarta.*)? If not, can I edit default template for the servlets?

Comment: EE 9 hasn't been release yet.  What are you going to run this on?

Comment: @stdunbar Tomcat 10 and Glassfish 6 have Jakarta EE 9 support

Comment: there is a related issue in JetBrains tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-249016

Comment: @PetrRastegaev yes, I reported that :)

Comment: IntelliJ has resolved the issue. I have been creating servlets and JSP through IntelliJ Java Enterprise Edition. You need to change the version from Java EE8 to Jakarta EE9 in the wizard.